# Populate properties of an object from array of String

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

If we have an object in groovy, for example Customer[name, email, phone] and a String in the form

```
String infoLine = "Stanislav,stanislav@stackoverflow.com,004612345678"
```

What is the easiest way to parse that string and populate the fields of that object?

(The example string we can split, that is why the question is from array of String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a constructor

```
Customer(String name, String email, String phone)
```

You can do:

```
new Customer(*infoLine.split(','))
```

If you don't want to write a constructor, you can get Groovy to create one for you:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@TupleConstructor
class Customer {
    String name
    String email
    String phone
}

String infoLine = "Stanislav,stanislav@stackoverflow.com,004612345678" 

new Customer(*infoLine.split(','))
```

Or even better, `@Immutable` as this makes the properties `final`

```
@Immutable
class Customer {
    String name
    String email
    String phone
}
```

Another option (assuming your fields are defined in the order they appear in the string, and there are no other fields), would be to generate a map of `[name: 'aaa', emai... etc`, and tell groovy to convert the map to a Customer like:

```
class Customer {
    String name
    String email
    String phone
}

String infoLine = "Stanislav,stanislav@stackoverflow.com,004612345678" 

def customer = [
    Customer.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }*.name,
    infoLine.split(',')
].transpose().collectEntries() as Customer
```

But this feels kinda brittle, and it's probably quicker to add the annotation or constructor.

Comment: Is it possible to skip writing the constructor? Is there even a faster way?

Comment: @StanislavIvanov gave you a few more options 

Comment: thanks, the second option is best as it is what I was looking for exactly. It is easier to read than the last option especially for unexperienced programmers.